# Button does nothing, but why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am basically only trying to get R.id.button1 to open up Google in a web browser, not sure whats wrong!

No errors, it just does nothing when pressing the button, I am using the emulator.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        }
    }




        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `savedInstanceState` equal to `null`? What did your debugger show you when you added useful breakpoints?

Comment: You're only setting the OnClickListener when savedInstanceState is null

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here :

```
btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

replace it with :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And implement `View.OnClickListner` in order to get the `onClick` method

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListner {

    /*
        some code here
    */

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
    }
}
```

You can also do it like this :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));              
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your button is in your fragment layout (right?)
then you should handle your button's events in your fragment, not in the activity!

Answer (score 1):

Your `onCreate()` method should be like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `OnClickListner`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListner {
Button btn;
```

Define the listener to your `button1`.

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

use a switch in onClick() method to handle several views:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {        
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
           startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
        break;
        default:
            //code..
        break;
        };
}
```

other way to set the listener to your button:

```
 btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener{
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
        }
```